# How do I measure the distribution of an attribute of a given population?

Tags: statistics, distribution, normal-distribution

I have a catalog of 900 applications.
I need to determine how their reliability is distributed as a whole. (i.e. is it normal).

I can measure the reliability of an individual application.

How can I determine the reliability of the group as a whole without measuring each one?

Comment: What questions should I be asking to make the question less open-ended?

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty open-ended question!  Overall, distribution fitting can be quite challenging and works best with large samples (100's or even 1000's).  It's generally better to pick a modeling distribution based on known characteristics of the process you're attempting to model than to try purely empirical fitting.

If you're going to go empirical, for a start you could take a random sample, measure the reliability scores (whatever you're using for that) of your sample, sort them, and plot them vs normal quantiles.  If they fall along a relatively straight line the normal distribution is a plausible model, and you can estimate sample mean and variance to parameterize it.  You can apply the same idea of plotting vs quantiles from other proposed distributions to see if they are plausible as well.

Watch out for behavior in the tails, in particular.  Pretty much by definition the tails occur rarely and may be under-represented in your sample.  Like all things statistical, the larger the sample size you can draw on the better your results will be.

I'd also add that my prior belief would be that a normal distribution wouldn't be a great fit.  Your reliability scores probably fall on a bounded range, tend to fall more towards one side or the other of that range.  If they tend to the high range, I'd predict that they get lopped off at the end of the range and have a long tail to the low side, and vice versa if they tend to the low range.